# Can't search on has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :jobs, force: true

  create_table :enquirers, force: true

  create_table :jobs_enquirers, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "job_id"
    t.integer  "enquirer_id"
  end
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :jobs_enquirer, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :enquirer, through: :jobs_enquirer
end

class JobsEnquirer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :enquirer
end

class Enquirer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs_enquirers
  has_many :jobs, through: :jobs_enquirers
end

enquirer = Enquirer.create!
job = Job.create!(enquirer: enquirer)
puts Job.where(enquirer: enquirer)
```

But when I try to get the `post` query failed.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column jobs.enquirer_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."enquirer_id" = 1
```

How could I specify the correct table an column?

Full gist : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1cf19055e4ed147fd2f092ac7c78c9db

EDIT:

I finally add the join table explicitly, and fetch it with a scope.

In my model

```
# app/models/job.rb
scope :with_enquirer, ->(enquirer) { joins(:jobs_enquirer).where(jobs_enquirer: { job_id: job }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You setup your association as `many to many` in db structure, but expect to use it, as `one to many` in code structure.

So you should either rework it to one `Post` has many `Comment`, then:

1. Remove table `comments_posts` and model `CommentPost`
2. Setup foreign key `post_id` in `Comment`
3. Make 2 association: a). add `has_many :comments` in `Post` b). `belongs_to :post' in`Comment`

Or make them as `Post` has and belongs to many `Comment`, then:

1. `Post`: `has_many :comments_posts` and `has_many :comments, through: :comments_post`
2. `Comment`: `has_many :comments_posts` and `has_many :posts, through: :comments_post` (`has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't have `through` option. And you should better go with `has_many ... through:` association

The way you should choose depends on your business requirements and app logic

Comment: Thanks. For the first proposition I don't want to add info into `Job` about Enquirer. In my app I will have many join tables. For the second proposition I know it work but what happen if `Job` can have only `enquirer` and not many? I rewrote my question with more relevant model name

Comment: If your `Job` has only one `Enquirer`, then why you need `JobEnquirer` table? (btw I would suggest to rename your table `JobsEnquirers` is not a conventional name or even rename it in something more close to natural language)

Comment: Because the `Enquirer` have (in my app) a lot's of columns already. In specific case it needs a job but most of the time no. Thanks for your second tips.

Comment: Do you usually load all this fields at once or do often load only part of them? Big table is not good, but joins are even worse, when you don't need them.

Comment: Most of the time all the field. It's a json api.

Comment: Then you won't win anything in splitting it in separate tables. I would suggest to put all the info in Enquirer and at least remove one useless join and make structure a bit simpler. From my point of vier, your current approach gives you more cons, then pros. One of possible solution is to split enquirer into 2 tables (think about good names, I will go with Enquirer and EnquirerData). Then `Post` `has_many` `Enquirer`. `Enquirer` `belongs_to` `Post`. `Enquirer` `has_one` `EnquirerData`. `EnquirerData` `belongs_to` `Post`